# cancel method doesn't work in Count Down Timer class?

Tags: android, methods, counter

I designed an app that has two buttons one to start a counter and a second one to stop. Starting the counter works fine but when I click the stop button the app crashes.
What is the problem with my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int i=1;
    TextView txt;
    Counter ct;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void bustart(View view) {
        startTime();
    }

    public void buop(View view) {
        ct.cancel();
    }

    public void startTime(){
        i=1;
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ct=new Counter(5000,1000);
        ct.start();
    }

    public  class Counter extends CountDownTimer{

        Counter(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval){
            super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            i++;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txt.setText("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: Where are your Buttons declared and initialized?

Comment: Where are you calling the `buop` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Insure You Are give `buop` onClick to your Xml.,,Like that

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="buop"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:visibility="visible"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="bustart"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"

    />
```

Take boolean to ensure timer is start other if you cancel button without start is crash generate. otherwise your code fine...

```
boolean timerStart=false;


public void bustart(View view) {
    if(!timerStart) {

      timerStart=true;
        startTime();
    }
 }


 public void buop(View view) {

    if(timerStart) {
        timerStart=false;
        ct.cancel();
    }
    }
```

[image]